# JAVA-STREAM : re-use double a DoubleStream

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, supplier

I need a trick to solve this problem i'm using Java 1.8 And I retrieved a an object from a method that returns a DoubleStream object. So, the problem is I could not reuse the stream after it has been consumed.

Here is the first version of the code :

```
 DoubleStream stream = object.getvalueStream(a,b);
 if(condtion)
   stream.map(v -> v * 2);
 stream.forEach(value -> {
        // do something
  }
```

The problem is that once the condition is true, the stream is consumed And I can not reuse it. So I tried to use a supplier to return a doubleStream from supplier and iterate overt it.

But still the same problem as I try to recover the stream from my stream object which is already used.

Here is my updated code :

```
      DoubleStream stream = object.getvalueStream(a,b);
      if(condtion)
      stream.map(v -> v * 2);
      Supplier>DoubleStream> streamSupplier = () -> DoubleStream.of(stream.toArray());
      streamSupplier.get().forEach(value -> {
           //Do something
```

But I still have the same problem since I create my supplier from my stream already used if the condition is true.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You get a new `Stream` from each intermediate operation, so you should be doing `stream = stream.map(...);`

Comment: but not with "terminal operations" such as `.forEach(...)`

Comment: May it will be better if you can explain why not interested in collecting and reusing the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> once the condition is true, the stream is consumed And I can not reuse it

*Intermediate* operations (e.g. `map`) return a new stream, so you need to reassign the stream after the intermediate operation (`map`).

I.e.

```
DoubleStream stream = object.getvalueStream(a,b);
if (condition) {
    stream = stream.map(v -> v * 2);
}
stream.forEach(value -> {
    // do something
}
```

Note *terminal* operations (e.g. `foreach`) do not return a stream. So if you want many terminal operations, you should collect the stream so it can be reused.

Note also, there is also an intermediate version of `foreach` called `peek` if you wish to chain `foreach` (`peek`) calls.

Answer (score 2):

`Streams` in Java are not up to be reused. You should `collect` the result and stream twice like

```
List<Double> doubles = object.getvalueStream(a,b).boxed().collect(toList());

if(condition) {
    doubles = doubles.stream().map(v -> v * 2).boxed().collect(toList);
}

// and further processing here
doubles.stream().forEach(v ->
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map() if it is important for you to keep the stream without collecting it. The only drawback in this approach is that you have to check the condition each time

```
DoubleStream stream = object.getvalueStream(a,b).map(v-> condition ? v*2 : v).forEach(...);
```

Or just assign the right Stream to the variable

```
DoubleStream stream = condition ? object.getvalueStream(a,b).map(v->v*2) : object.getvalueStream(a,b).map(v->v*2).forEach(...);
```

Comment: What is the reason to perform `n` additional checks instead of one?

Comment: @m.antkohetwicz just to keep the stream if it is required by the task, but no practical reason. It is obviously better to collect the stream into the list and then use it as much as you need but did not want to repeat the previous answers

Comment: it has to do ```n``` mappings anyway, an extra condition check wont impact performance much, especially with branch prediction.

Comment: @wilmol that's obviously not a true because when condition is false then **not even a single mapping** needs to be done. We don't know anything neither about collection size nor condition statistics - how can you say that it won't affect performance? What if we have billions of items, condition is true in 99% of cases and the method is being run in a loop?

Comment: OK, if the condition is false the redundant ```v -> v``` mapping slows it down. But not much. I assume ```condition``` is cached in a ```boolean``` variable, so branch prediction should optimise it. I ran a JMH benchmark (10 iterations, 1 billion elements (```IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000```)). 1st no map operation. 2nd map with always false condition, 3rd map operation with just ```v-> v``` (no condition). 1st  5406ms avg, 2nd 5684ms avg, 3rd 5656ms avg.